# Which Version should I Upgrade to 2.1.10 or 2.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade

My current Magento installation is `2.1.7 CE`, and my website does not require any B2B features available in 2.2.

**So should I update to 2.2 or 2.1.10 ?**

Will all the security patches, be available for 2.1.10

If I should upgrade it ? Is there any noteworthy performance improvement in 2.2 ?

Comment: Obviously , it's better to upgrade your Magento version to the latest, (2.2.1)
There are some security updates, comes along with the latest version. So it's always recommended.

Comment: @MGento So you mean to say those Security patches will not be available with 2.1.10 version ? Do you have any documentation or link of article where i can read more about this

Comment: As far as I know, there are no patches available, you have to update to the new version through composer. Anyone, please correct me if I am wrong. 
https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-221-2110-and-2017-security-update

Comment: @MGento Right you have to do that via composer , i just wanted to know will 2.1 series will get all the update that 2.2 series does , so if check the the release docs or even the link you shared the issue /security patch is applied to both 2.2.1 and 2.1.10

Comment: While analyzing the release notes, we can see there are some bug fixes for in the Magento2.2.1 . So I think, its always good to upgrade to the latest.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.1CE.html  and   
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.10CE.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.2.1 contains many more bug fixes, is a more up-to-date version of Magento and of course contains all the security fixes that are also present in 2.1.10.

If possible, you should always upgrade to the latest version. However, because 2.2 is such a big jump, this might not always be possible. In my instance, one extension that I'm using does not support 2.2 yet, and Composer complains about version constraints — I have no choice but to wait and to upgrade to 2.1.10 instead.

Apart from that, 2.2 needs a lot of testing, especially if you have a very customised instance. For more information about all the changes in 2.2, check out the [official 2.2 release notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html), and [2.2.1 release notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.1CE.html).